# Retrieving encrypted column 'xxx' with CommandBehavior=SequentialAccess is not supported

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2016, azure-sql-database, always-encrypted

I have setup a Azure SQL Database and enabled Always Encrypted.

One of the column (column3) is `varchar(Max)`.

When I query the database from SSMS without using `"column encryption setting=enabled"`, I can see that all the columns have binary data.

When I query the database from SSMS using `"column encryption setting=enabled"`, I am getting an error as below:

> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Retrieving encrypted column 'column3' with CommandBehavior=SequentialAccess is not supported.

This is what my table definition looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable](
    [column1] [varchar](2000) ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK_Auto1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
    [column2] [datetime] ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK_Auto1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
    [column3] [varchar](max) ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK_Auto1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL
)
```

If I remove the encryption on column3, everything works fine and I can see decrypted values.

Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: What is the version of SSMS you are using, and what is the build date of Azure SQL DB according to SELECT @@VERSION;?

Comment: SSMS Version: SQL Server 2016 - CTP 3
Azure SQL DB Version: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Dec 16 2015 01:05:50   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation

Comment: CTP 3 what? 3.0? 3.1? 3.2? You should make sure to download CTP 3.2, which was released this week.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I have added the picture of About box

Comment: Grab the latest which is 13.0.900.73

Comment: Its nothing to do with the version here. I have 13.0.11000.48 and getting the same error.

Comment: Can any one tell me why the .NET framework version is 4.0 when it is supposed to be 4.6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer from the Always Encrypted team here.

SQL Server and Azure SQL DB do not allow querying VARCHAR(MAX) column with "column encryption setting=enabled" from SSMS as SSMS employs Sequential Access for streaming potentially large varchar(MAX) values. SSMS enforces this choice by design as it provides a mechanism to query partial byte locations in large objects ( thus avoiding storage of entire large blob in memory). However, in contrast, Always Encrypted does not allow partial decryption for encrypted columns. This limitation stems from the fact that we use block ciphers and also store HMAC in the encrypted cell, without the full cell value we cannot validate the HMAC and decrypt the data.

As an alternative, you can query a varchar(max) with "column encryption setting=enabled" from a ADO.Net client (without using SequentialAccess).

Comment: If that is the case then why I am able to get data on the client end ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the SSMS 16.3, released in August 2016. You can now query and decrypt varchar(max) and other LOB columns.